# Jquery .append() appends on every event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have very minimal javascript and jquery knowledge, so the problem is, when click with mouse "li" tab and press ENTER jquery attach .append() on every mouse click event.

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
        let $ul_elem = $(event.target).parent().parent();
        const $li = '<li><input type="text" name="geras"></li>'
        
        if($(event.target).parent().prop("localName")=="li"){ 
            console.log($(this.event))
            $(window).on("keydown", function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $($ul_elem).append($li);
                    $($ul_elem).children().last().children().focus();   
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            $(window).unbind("keydown");
        }      
    })
```

in result if i click like 5 times with my mouse on the same li tab, it will create 5 new const $li elements and i dont want that.

Comment: What *do* you want?

Comment: Binding event handlers in context of another event handler is usually not what you want.

Comment: i want that no matter how much time user clicks with mouse on li tabe, it will only append 1 const $li

Comment: its really weird, jquery is like cashing of how much time i clicked li tabe, and just waiting for me to click enter, when i do that, its appending that to all cashed events....

Comment: You mean `li` _tag_ and not _tab_, right? Your code is pretty confusing. Do you want to append a `li` element on _keydown_ or on _click_? What is the relation between `tab` key and click event?

Comment: im sorry o just learning, but yes i meant li tag, I want to append new li tag when i press ENTER

Comment: "*jquery is like caching how many times I clicked*" - no, your code adds a new "keydown" handler each time you click.  So when you click 5 times, you have 5 handlers.  So when you press enter, the code runs 5 times - 1 for each time you clicked.    There's no issue with jquery here, it's just doing what you told it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid binding event handlers in context of another event handler. Your code currently rebinds the `keydown` handler on each click (when the if statements succeeds.) This is why the code appends several elements on each Enter. I guess you want to append `li` elements to `ul` elements conditionally. If yes this is one way of doing it:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul", function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(window).on("keydown", 'ul.active', function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 13) {
         const $ul_elem = $(this);
         const li = '<li><input type="text" name="geras"></li>'
         event.preventDefault();
         $ul_elem.append(li);
         $ul_elem.children().last().children().focus();   
         return false
     }
})
```

This makes the `keydown` handler work conditionally by using event delegation. In case you want to listen to the `keydown` event of `input` elements you can just code `$(document).on("keydown", 'input[type=text]', function(event) { ...` and there is no need to use `click` handler. I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve though.

> what I want to do is after i put text in my default li > input field and press ENTER i want to create new li in ul

This should do it:

```
$(document).on("keyup", 'li input[type=text]', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        const $ul_elem = $(this).closest('ul');
        const li = '<li><input type="text" name="geras"></li>'
        event.preventDefault();
        $ul_elem.append(li);
        $ul_elem.children().last().children().focus();   
    }
})
```

Comment: I used it because when i click on other field like textarea and press enter it stll creates new li in ul

Comment: Please check [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i doesn't work. I already have 1 const li field by default in html. what I want to do is after i put text in my default li > input field and press ENTER i want to create new li in ul

Comment: yes, thats i already managed to fix it by my self using using similar solution

Comment: @RugileVenskute That's great.